# Net-SSH Ruby Authentication

Tags: ruby, authentication, net-ssh

Can someone please shed some light on this issue I have with net-ssh. I am new to ruby and am working on this project.

How do I tell net ssh to use the username and password provided to connect to the servers without needing to have a shared key between my machine and those servers?

```
def connect
  Net::SSH.start("#{@servername}", "#{username}", :password => "#{password}") do |ssh|
    result = ssh.exec!("ls #{@dirname}").chomp
    puts result
  end #ssh
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear really what you're asking here. You appear to be using the Net::SSH api correctly, at least according to [its docs](http://net-ssh.github.com/ssh/v2/api/index.html).

One concern is your use of `"#{@servername}"` which is a redundant use of variable interpolation. There's no need for any of the quotes around `servername`, `username` or `password`.

However, please be clearer about your problem. Are you asking how you can pass these values in to your script, or is there a problem with Net::SSH accepting them?